# Eclipse export to runnable Jar with JavaFX: "copy required libraries into a sub-folder" works, but the other two options do not

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to package my application using JavaFx as a single .jar file.
I want it to be runnable from an environment where only java is installed, but not javaFX, so I'm trying to embed JavaFX inside of the jar.

If I do "copy required libraries into a sub-folder"
and I keep the "MyJarName_lib" and a "bin" folder near the extract jar, **all works fine**.

The "MyJarName_lib" contains all the jars dependencies and the bin contains all the dlls.
But in this way I get 3 files, I'm trying to package it all as a single jar.

If I do "Package required libraries .." or "Extract required libraries .."
Then when I run from the command line it I get

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

This happens either with no 'bin' folder, with the 'bin' folder near the jar or with the 'bin' folder added inside of the jar (at top level).

What should I do?

Comment: The _contents_ of the `bin` directory (i.e. the native libraries themselves) should be in the JAR at the top level.

Comment: whoops I mis readed you, now I'm going to try

Comment: Ok, YES, this does push the application forward.
another bug is emerging, but it looks unrelated.
If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Ok, no the new bug was not unrelated.
Now, if I do 'extract in the jar' I get a lot of 
""Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkUpdateRendering(long)""
while if I do 'package in the jar' then the application shut off without any message :-)

Comment: I believe JavaFX has three modules that have accompanying native libraries: `javafx.graphics`, `javafx.media`, and `javafx.web`. Did you include the native library for the web view implementation?

Comment: And to make a fat JAR with JavaFX you should only need to extract the JavaFX JARs into your JAR and include the native libraries in the top level. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Eclipse so I can't tell you what configurations you need to change. Also, you may also need to make the main class separate from your `Application` class (but that's a class-path vs module-path issue).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233607/discussion-between-marco-servetto-and-slaw).

Comment: Ok, sorted. I was using two diffent versions of 'bin' :-/
Somehow the old version works only outside, while the new versions is working both in and out.